# bind enter key to run a command in tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple find and replace widget in tkinter. I can press the button "RegexReplace" and it works good without any problems.

In this widget, we first type if label1, then label2, what I want is when I type text to be replaced in label called "To" and press Return Key, I want the app to do the find and replace without need to pressing the button "RegexReplace".

**Wanted**
When we are typing in "To" label,
if we press "Enter" key, run the function "find_and_replace"
if we press "ctrl+Enter" key run the function "find_and_replace".

Basically, I don't want to press "RegexReplace" button and when I hit enter after typing "To" field, I want the command to run.

## My attempts

```
l_to.bind("<Return>",  lambda x=[e_from,e_to]: find_and_replace(x[0],x[1]) ) # did not work
```

## MWE

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox

win = tk.Tk()
def find_and_replace(entry_from,entry_to):       
    # Get variables
    str_from = entry_from.get()
    str_to = entry_to.get()
    s = 'Quick brown fox jumped.'
    out = s.replace(str_from, str_to)
    tk.Label(win, text=out).pack(pady=4)

f = tk.Frame(win,height=200, width=200)
f.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20, pady=20)
f.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
        
# label frame: Find and Replace
lf00 = tk.LabelFrame(f, text='Replace this: Quick brown fox jumped.')
lf00.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(20, 2), pady=20, sticky='e')

l_from = tk.Label(lf00,text='From');l_from.grid(row=0,column=0)
l_to = tk.Label(lf00,text='To');l_to.grid(row=0,column=1)

e_from = tk.Entry(lf00);e_to = tk.Entry(lf00)
e_from.grid(row=1,column=0);e_to.grid(row=1,column=1)

b20 = tk.Button(lf00,text='RegexReplace',
                command= lambda x=[e_from,e_to]: find_and_replace(x[0],x[1]))
b20.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='w')

b21 = tk.Button(lf00,text='MultiReplace',
             command= lambda x=[e_from,e_to]: find_and_replace(x[0],x[1]))
b21.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='e')
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you say it 'did not work', what didn't work? Did the function not run? Did you not see the correct replacement? Did you get an error? Have you tried binding `'<Return>'` to `win` instead of the label?

Comment: Why would you bind `Enter` to the `Label` instead of the `Entry`?

Comment: Let say i want to replace 'fox' to 'bear', then when I type 'bear' and hit enter, nothing happens, I want to get it replaced as soon as type 'bear' and hit enter, without even clicking other buttons.

Comment: @Thingamabobs because i am learnig and i don't know where to bind.

Comment: Yeah, you should bind to the `Entry` instead of the `Label`

Comment: bound to Entry, got error, `TypeError: 'Event' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: See my answer below - you need to add an `event` param to the lambda (even if you're not using it) - you could also add it as an argument for `find_and_replace`, but that's unnecessary if you don't care about the event's content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the appropriate widget

```
e_from = tk.Entry(lf00);e_to = tk.Entry(lf00)
# add '_event' param to the lambda to absorb the unused event
e_from.bind("<Return>",  lambda _event, x=[e_from,e_to]: find_and_replace(x[0],x[1]) )
```

Comment: This solved the problem. the trick is event,x

Comment: You should have added an explanation to your changes in order to get useful to others as well.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it so others know this question has been answered.

Comment: i need 5 minutes to accept the answer, done it.